# stripping out the last two [end] with sed?

Tags: bash, text-processing, scripting, sed

I'm working on a script that improves the `fluxbox` 'menu', and my script has this line:

```
sed -i 's/\[end]//g' ~/.fluxbox/menu;sed -i '/^\s*$/d' ~/.fluxbox/menu
```

but this has the unfortunate effect of stripping out *all* of the `[end]` which is bad, I only want it to strip out the last two occurrences of `[end]` in that file. So how do I do it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest is probably to use `perl`'s *slurp* mode:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's/(.*)\[end]/$1/s;s/(.*)\[end]/$1/s;s/^\s*\n//gm' ~/.fluxbox/menu
```

Comment: unfortunately this perl line strips out the *first* [end] as well as the two at the end. Without the first [end] being in situ the menu cannot work!

Comment: @user205787, sorry, typo it was missing an `s`. Should work now.

Comment: thanks, its working by adding in an extra `\t[end]\` in the printf line. Thanks very much. The line now reads       ~~~~ printf '\t[end]\n\t[submenu] (My Menu)\n\t[include] (~/.fluxbox/usermenu)\n\t[end]\n\t[end]' >>~/.fluxbox/menu ~~~~

Answer (score 1):

Similar to `perl`'s slurp mode `sed` can read the entire file into the hold buffer ("hold space") so that the file contents can be treated as a single line in "pattern space" (for more information please see [sed and Multi-Line Search and Replace](http://austinmatzko.com/2008/04/26/sed-multi-line-search-and-replace/)).

Having just one big single line, the greedy nature of `sed` regular expressions then makes it easy to strip out the last two occurrences of `[end]` in the given file (virtually identical to the Perl regex logic of [Stephane Chazelas' accepted solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102227)).

```
#sed -i -n -e '1h;1!H;${;g; s/\(.*\)\[end\]/\1/; s/\(.*\)\[end\]/\1/; p;}'  file  # does not work on Mac OS X 10.6.8
sed -n -i -e '1h;1!H;${;g; s/\(.*\)\[end\]/\1/; s/\(.*\)\[end\]/\1/; p;}' file   # note: -n precedes -i

# ... plus deleting all blank lines
sed -n -i -e '1h;1!H;${;g; s/\(.*\)\[end\]/\1/; s/\(.*\)\[end\]/\1/; s/^[[:space:]]*\n//; s/\n[[:space:]]*$//; s/\n[[:space:]]*\n/\
/g; p;}' file
```